# Arduino multiple serial module usage

Tags: arduino, serial, robotics, gps, imu

I'm stuck at this seemingly simple thing. I have a NMEA GPS module. It doesn't matter how it operates, it just transmit serial data stream at a baud rate of 38400.

I have an arduino Mega which has several hardware serial modules. If i directly connect GPS Tx to Arduinos Tx pin (and program arduino to not to use default serial module, `Serial0`) then i can observe raw GPS sentences transmitted by the GPS module using the arduino serial monitor.

What I really want is to read the GPS module to arduino `Serial1` port and forward the receiving data through the default serial port `Serial0` without doing anything. So that i should be able to monitor the data from the serial monitor as exactly in the previous case.

I tried something like follows, but it's not working (it gives a stream of digits, i tried doing all the possible changes but nothing worked)

```
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(38400); // the default serial module, serial0
  Serial1.begin(38400); // GPS is connected to this
}

void loop(){
  if(Serial1.available()){ // if GPS data available
    Serial.print(Serial1.read()); // write it to serial0
  }
}
```

Hope someone here will be able to give me some solution.

Comment: Shouldn't you be connecting GPS Tx to Arduino Rx (not Tx)?

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick nope, in the first case it should be Tx bacause arduino is not receiving anything, GPS Tx behave like arduino Tx.

Answer (score 2):

`Serial::print()` converts the bytes to an ASCII representation. Use `Serial::write()` instead.

Comment: As Ignacio stated, `Serial.print()` converts the input to ASCII while `Serial.write()` "passes through" the binary data. Here is the link to the Arduino reference: http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write